# How to give multidimensional array a value for each 'cells'

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, array

I'm not a programmer at all, but I need to write a script to cut a file and produce a multidimensional array from this file.

I'm a chemist, so my array should be something like:

```
[pe][pH][element][concentration].
```

This way, I'll be able to plot concentration change for a single element with *pH* and *pe*.

So I wrote this script to cut my input file and index *pe*, *pH* and species, but now I'm stuck. I have no idea how to complete it.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    inputFile='test.inp'

    awk '/Distribution of species/ {f=1} /Saturation indices/ {f=0} f' $inputFile > distriPack.inout
   csplit -z -f distri_ distriPack.inout /Distribution/ {*}
   sed -i '1,5d; $d' distri_*
   sed -i 's/^ *//' distri_*
   cut -d ' ' -f1 distri_* | sort | uniq > especes.inp
   grep -E "pH  =   " $inputFile | cut -d '=' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 4 > ph.inp
   grep -E "pe  =   " $inputFile | cut -d '=' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 4 > pe.inp

   declare -a tableVariable=(ipe ipH ies)

  ipe=0 
  tablepe=0
  for pe in cat "$pe.inp"
  do 
      if ([ $ipe -eq 0 ] || pePrev=pe)
          then 
           tablepe=$((tablepe+1))
           ipe=$((ipe+1))
           pePrev=$pe
           fi
             ipH=0
             tablepH=0
             for pH in cat "$pH.inp"
             do 
             if ([ $ipH -eq 0 ] || pHPrev=pH )
             then 
             tablepH=$((tablepH+1)) > tablepH.inp
             ipH=$((ipH+1))
             pHPrev=$pH
             fi
                ies=0
                tablees=0
                for espece in cat "$espece.inp"
                do
                    if ([ $ies -eq 0 ] || especePrev=espece )
                    then 
            #                       indEspece=0
            #                       for espece in distri_$pe
            #                       do 
            #                          if ([ $indEspece -eq 0 ])
                       maVariable= grep -E "espece" < distri_10  | cut -d ' ' -f 1 

                       ${tableVariable[ $((ipe)) $((ipH)) $((ies)) ]}=$((maVariable))
          #                     done            
                    ies=$((ies+1))
                    tablees=$((tablees+1))
                    especePrev=$espece
                    fi  
                    done
                   done

           done
```

## val=${monTableau[${i_pe} ${i_pH} ${es} ${pa}]}>monTableau.inp

I'll like to have something like : `for [pe][pH][specie]=[0][12][15]`

indexTable=concentration.

But I don't know how to say in bash `for pe = i, pH = j` and `specie=k` and `do indexTable[i][j][k]=value` of the second columns of the file Distri_(pe/pH index value) for the line corresponding to the specie of index k.
Here you have "some" lines from my input file :

```
    >Initial solution 1. \newline
    >Description of solution 
    >pH = 0.0 
    >pe = 0.0 
    >Distribution of species 
    >Species Molality log Activity 
    >H+       1.1e+00 1.0e+00 
    >OH-      1.5e-14 9.5e-15 
    >Am+2     0.0e+00 0.0e+00


    >Initial solution 2. pe 0 pH 0.5 
    >Description of solution 
    >pH = 0.5 
    >pe = 0.0 
    >Distribution of species 
    >Species Molality Log Activity 
    >H+ 4.1e-01 3.1e-01 
    >OH- 4.5e-14 3.1e-14 
    >Am+2 0.0e+00 0.0e+00
```

I'd like to get something like that : outputfile_[pe value].out where data would be ordered like that :

```
    >Column 1    C2 .....      Cn 
    >Specie\pH   0             n 
    >H+          [H+] at pH=0  [H+] at pH=n
```

etc

Comment: Hi Nicolas. I'm thinking about to use awk to solve your issue, but I need some sample input (paste some lines of your input file, if possible) and the desired output for that sample.

Comment: Here you have "some" lines from my input file :
Initial solution 1.
Description of solution
pH  =   0.0
pe  =   0.0    
Distribution of species
Species Molality      log Activity  
H+         1.1e+00  1.0e+00
OH-       1.5e-14  9.5e-15  
Am+2    0.0e+00   0.0e+00

Comment: Initial solution 2. pe 0 pH 0.5
Description of solution
pH  =   0.5
pe  =   0.0
Distribution of species
Species Molality      Log Activity
H+         4.1e-01   3.1e-01
OH-       4.5e-14   3.1e-14  
Am+2    0.0e+00   0.0e+00

I'd like to get something like that :
outputfile_[pe value].out
where data would be ordered like that :
Column 1   C2   .....       Cn
Specie\pH  0                   n
H+             [H+] at pH=0 [H+] at pH=n
....

Comment: Hi Nicolas. Can you please edit your question and put this information there? Here in the comments everything seems to be in the same line.. Is this the case? A formated input and desired output should point me to the right direction to help you...

Comment: Sorry @Nicolas, but I still don't understand what should be the final result and what fields should be put in what position in a multidimensional array...

Comment: I have a big file wich is a simulation of chemical solutions, where i'm varing pe and pH, and i'd like to get from this one big files, as much "little files" for all the pe variation.
I'd like those file to display concentration variation of species with the pH...

Answer (score 0):

emphasized textI'm not sure if you want to print the ">" sign in the output or if it exists in the input... Please, give me a feedback so I could make the corrections in the script.

This should **do the job** if the **input** and **output** are **exactly** as you described:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
{
# Set the INDEX for each 'Initial Solution'
if ($1==">Initial"){
        gsub(/\./,"",$3);
        INDEX=$3;}

#Discard lines with 'Species' or 'Description'
if (($1==">Description")||($1==">Species")) next;

#Remove '>' from the first field
gsub(/>/,"",$1)

#Set the labels of the rows
PH[0]="Column"
PE[0]="Specie\\ph"
H[0]="H+"
OH[0]="OH-"
AM[0]="Am+2"

#Set other values (pH, pe, etc)
if ($1=="pH") PH[INDEX]=$3
if ($1=="pe") PE[INDEX]=$3
if ($1=="H+") H[INDEX]=$2" "$3
if ($1=="OH-") OH[INDEX]=$2" "$3
if ($1=="Am+2") AM[INDEX]=$2" "$3
}

# Print each array.
END {
for (i = 0; i <= INDEX; i++) printf("%s\t",i)
printf("\n")
for (i = 0; i <= INDEX; i++) printf("%s\t",PH[i])
printf("\n")
for (i = 0; i <= INDEX; i++) printf("%s\t",PE[i])
printf("\n")
for (i = 0; i <= INDEX; i++) printf("%s\t",H[i])
printf("\n")
for (i = 0; i <= INDEX; i++) printf("%s\t",OH[i])
printf("\n")
for (i = 0; i <= INDEX; i++) printf("%s\t",AM[i])
printf("\n")
}
```

Some notes:

1. The first line (#!/usr/bin/awk) should point to the location of awk in your machine (try `whereis awk` at the prompt)
2. At the final block, the \t inserts a 'tab' between the fields. You may replace it for \t\t for 2 tabs, a comma ',' or simply a space ' ' to fit your needs.
3. Save this script and to use it, simply do: `awk -f script.name.awk input.file.inp`